# Can graph with lines be generated in gnuplot in a linux terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

I want graphs with lines to be generated in gnuplot rather than points in a terminal. I have only terminal to work with and no gui interface (Centos). 
i tried installing png/wxt terminal which failed. I want the output to be saved in a file but with lines unlike one with dumb terminal.

Answer (score 4):

**Displaying nice graphics in a terminal emulator window or on the bare linux console**

The current recommendation for displaying graphics from gnuplot to the linux console (i.e. no windowing system at all) is to use a console terminal emulator such as yaft (https://github.com/uobikiemukot/yaft) that supports sixel graphics.  With yaft as your console terminal you can run gnuplot and select `set term sixel` to generate very nice in-line graphics.

You can do essentially the same thing using xterm, so long as your copy of xterm was built with sixel graphics support.  You must select the vt340 emulation mode. This allows in-line graphics generated by a remote machine that you have connected to via ssh.

```
$ xterm -ti 340
xterm> ssh some.remote.machine
  [remote prompt] gnuplot
  gnuplot> set term sixel
  gnuplot> plot ...
```

[image]

**Generating graphics to a file from a dumb terminal window**

However none of this is necessary in order to create an output file from a terminal that is not capable of graphics.  Gnuplot terminals png/tikz/pdf/postscript/emf/... etc all work without any requirement for terminal display.  You can preview the plot with `set term dumb` and then switch to your prefered format for saving to a file.

```
 set term dumb
 plot sin(x) with lines   # ugly plot but indicates ranges, etc
 set term pdf
 set output 'myplot.pdf'
 replot
```

Comment: XTerm man page has "_Valid values include vt52, vt100, vt101, vt102, vt220, and vt240 (the “vt” is optional).  The default is “vt420”._" — No vt340... Could you please tell something about this little mistery? ? PS: my `xterm` supports `-ti 340` and `set term sixel` works nicely, but `vt340` is undocumented...

Comment: I cannot explain the lack of mention in your man page, but the xterm source code for sixel graphics support lists: `/* sixel scrolling:
 * VK100/GIGI ? (did it even support Sixel?)
 * VT125      unsupported
 * VT240      unsupported
 * VT241      unsupported
 * VT330      mode setting
 * VT382      ?
 * VT340      mode setting
 * dxterm     ?
 */
`